# Cannot access Contacts through Office365 Unified API

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I was using the Office365 Unified API, most of the endpoints like Mail, Calendar, Files, Groups work OK besides the Contacts.

I fire this kind of request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/<tenant>/contacts
```

And I am getting an empty response even though I have created some contacts through my Office365 online interface. 
Response:

```
 {
    "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/<tenant>/$metadata#contacts",
    "value":[]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The contacts being returned by that request are Organizational contacts. 
The contacts that you created are most likely personal contacts. Personal contacts are not exposed in the API yet (they will be very soon).

Comment: Thank you Yina, yes that is something I saw in their API documentation. Can you give me a hint how to create Organizational contacts from the online Office365 account?

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently no programmatic way (through the unified API) to create Org contacts.  You can create org contacts on premises and synchronize them to the cloud through AD Connect.